# Ranking multiple entries sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which I log the the visits each user has on it's profile page.
Given the fact that the table entries are like

```
 id user time ip
```

is it possible to display the ranking of a certain user's visits using a sigle query?

Example: Your ranking: #400 - meaning the user ranks 400 on the number of page hits.

Comment: Yes. Simply group by count and order by count. You can always append the actual rank later in your programming (by adding 1 to a number while iterating through results)

Comment: select count(user) from urtable order by time;

Comment: @h2ooooooo, this seems ok for applying the ranking to my all users periodicaly (i am looking through this option as well) - but in this case I only want to display the ranking for a given user. I have tried the query with count and group BY and order BY - seems to run pretty slow (on almost 1 M entries).

Comment: Do you have an index on the column `user`?

Comment: I created an index just before running some tests and writing the comment. 2 seconds query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method.  The innermost subquery counts the number of visits for each user.  The next subquery calculates a variable called `@uservisits` which stores the value for the given user.  The outer query then uses this to calculate the rank:

```
select count(*) as rank
from (select user, numvisits, @uservisits := if(user = $user, numvisits, @uservisits)
      from (select user, count(*) as numvisits
            from table t
            group by user
           ) t cross join
           (select @uservisits := 0) init
     ) t
where numvisits >= @uservisits
```

Comment: Very fast and exactly what I needed. 
Please edit $uservisits to @uservisits
Thank you, !  :)

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thing?

```
SELECT  @rank := @rank+1 AS rank, province, cityCount
    FROM
      ( SELECT  @rank := 0 ) z
    JOIN
      ( SELECT  province, COUNT(*) AS cityCount
            FROM  Canada
            GROUP BY  province
      ) x
    ORDER BY  cityCount DESC;
+------+---------------------------+------------+
| rank | province                  | cityCount  |
+------+---------------------------+------------+
|    1 | Quebec                    |       1045 |
|    2 | Ontario                   |        891 |
|    3 | British Columbia          |        716 |
|    4 | Saskatchewan              |        573 |
|    5 | Alberta                   |        573 |
|    6 | Newfoundland and Labrador |        474 |
|    7 | Nova Scotia               |        331 |
|    8 | Manitoba                  |        299 |
|    9 | New Brunswick             |        210 |
|   10 | Yukon                     |        114 |
|   11 | Nunavut                   |        107 |
|   12 | Northwest Territories     |         94 |
|   13 | Prince Edward Island      |         57 |
+------+---------------------------+------------+
```